"Aggregator microservice" or just gateway api?
I wondered whether it's common to develop a microservice that "aggregates" responses from various microservices and send the composited result back to the gateway api.
Or is it more common to let the gateway api handle the job of composition and serve?
Something like this: (Sorry for the bad topology)
           o
         / MS
       o
    / AMS \
  o        o
GW API     MS


Aggregator services are very common, I've seen them most often when utilizing the Backend For FrontEnd pattern, but it is generally very common to create composite micro-services.
